# Text overflow in container

Tags: html, css, text, overflow

I am trying to figure out how to make the text and my arrow not overflow into the next cell. I have tried giving it a min-width and that didn't seem to work. I know I may have to use media queries when it gets that small but if anyone has an idea as to what I have to do when it is that small so that it doesn't overflow, that would help so much.

Here's a photo of the issue:

[image]

I created a JS Fiddle of the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/e9uv08wh/6/

```css
    
    a{
      
      
          color: #544f47;
    height: 3.4em;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-left: 1em;
    border-bottom: .0625em solid #544f47;
    line-height: 3.4em;
    display: block;
  

         
}

i.fa.fa-chevron-right {
  float: right;
         margin-right: .5em;
         padding-top: .3em;
          line-height:3em;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>


</div>
<span><div class="border"><a class="newnav" href="https://www.google.com/">Google<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></div></span>
<span><div class="border"><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google Google Google<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></div> </span>
<span><div class="border"><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></div></span> 
<span><div class="border"><a href="https://www.google.com/">Submit to Google<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a> </div></span>
<span><div class="border"><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a> </div></span>
<span><div class="border"><a class="newnav" href="https://www.google.com/">Google<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a> </div></span>
```

Thank you.

Desired result when small:

[image]

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: I added it into my question. Does that make more sense? @GerardoBLANCO

Comment: @Cakers dont worry it does make sense

Comment: A lot better jajaja. Does @gibberish answer helped you?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO almost, I'm still struggling with the content moving into the next row. It fixed the messy overlapping issue but I'm still trying to figure out how to not have the content from one row go into the next.

Comment: @Cakers is my answer what you mean or did you want the text all on one line even when inside its container?

Comment: Check my answer, if it doesnt help you, please comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve what you are trying to do. Applying `overflow: hidden` to your divs would prevent the overflow but its not an optimal solution.

I would rebuild your HTML & CSS like so:

```
<div class="border"><a class="newnav" href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
<div class="border"><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google Google Google</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
<div class="border"><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
<div class="border"><a href="https://www.google.com/">Submit to Google</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> </div>
<div class="border"><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> </div>
<div class="border"><a class="newnav" href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> </div>

.border {
  height: 55px;
  border-bottom: .0625em solid #544f47;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

 a { 
    color: #544f47;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-left: 1em;
    display: block;
}

i.fa.fa-chevron-right {
  display: block;
  margin-right: .5em;
  padding-top: .3em;
  line-height:3em;
}
```

You can see how this behaves in this jsfiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/95cgh68n/1/**

Using the divs as flexboxes allows you to setup how you would like the child elements to be arrayed. This solution should at least cut down on the number of media queries you need to use.

Here is a great guide to flex box if you arent familiar with it: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: wow! This answer helps a lot! Thank you so much @Aonghas M I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @Cakers no worries man. Message me if you need help with anything or you want to know why I lay it out the way I did. If you need the text to remain on one line then I recommend using media queries to reduce the font size.

Comment: Good answer - and good idea pointing out Flexbox. Well done. +1

Answer (score 2):

To stop the overflow, you can use css `div.border{overflow:hidden}`, but you might wish to refactor your html to have only the text hidden and to always show the arrow.

Also, you are using `<span>` tags to delineate your rows. You should use DIVs for this - because spans are by design inline tags, and you appear to want to break the rows, which is what DIVs do. Change the spans to divs.

Comment: Changing the spans to divs and using the overflow hidden the content still goes into other rows. I'm wondering if there is a way to make a min-width for example so that the content doesn't have to go into the next row. Thank you for taking a look at this question. I very much appreciate it. @gibberish

Comment: this is also a good answer ^. Overflow is always something useful to understand and this answer helps keep things on one line. A combination of our answers may work best

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to change the css, you can apply the `overflow: hidden` to you `<a>` tags

> CAUTION: i added body width to 40vh to reproduce a smalle screen.

Hope this helps :)

```css
a {
  color: #544f47;
  height: 3.4em;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-left: 1em;
  border-bottom: .0625em solid #544f47;
  line-height: 3.4em;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

i.fa.fa-chevron-right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: .5em;
  padding-top: .3em;
  line-height: 3em;
}

body {
  width: 40vh;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>


</div>
<span><div class="border"><a class="newnav" href="https://www.google.com/">Google<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></div></span>
<span><div class="border"><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google Google Google<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></div> </span>
<span><div class="border"><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></div></span>
<span><div class="border"><a href="https://www.google.com/">Submit to Google<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a> </div></span>
<span><div class="border"><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a> </div></span>
<span><div class="border"><a class="newnav" href="https://www.google.com/">Google<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a> </div></span>
```